# JQuery load image repeatedly

Tags: image, jquery

I've got a rudimentary remote control API for a PC which accepts commands via AJAX (Move mouse, click, send key, etc.) It also serves images for the specified screen

The API has a front-end which is mostly jQuery-powered.

I have an `img` tag which shows the currently selected screen's screenshot and has mouse move/click events which call the appropriate APIs behind the scenes.

The screen image is currently updated like this:

```
    function UpdateScreen() {
        $("#Screenshot").attr("src", "./AJAX/UI/GetScreen.aspx?Screen=" + encodeURIComponent(targetScreen) + "&Date=" + encodeURIComponent(Date()));
        setTimeout('UpdateScreen()', 3000);
    }
```

Which works ok but is ridiculously inefficient - Either the image loads in less than 3 seconds in which case, my refresh rate is lower than it should be or  in more than 3 second in which case the old request is terminated (eg mobile over 2G).

How can I reload an image as soon as it finishes loading? Even better, is there any way I can do it in the same way as an AJAX call rather than relying on the browser? That way, I can catch failures, have a progress bar and also control how the image redraws (using something like a back-buffer).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the native Javascript `Image` object and wait for onload to fire before setting the timeout...

```
function UpdateScreen() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    $("#Screenshot").attr("src", this.src);
    setTimeout(UpdateScreen, 3000);
  }
  img.src = "./AJAX/UI/GetScreen.aspx?Screen=" + encodeURIComponent(targetScreen) + "&Date=" + encodeURIComponent(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the load event on the image. i.e:

```
$("#Screenshot").load(UpdateScreen);
  function UpdateScreen(){
  $("#Screenshot").attr("src", "./AJAX/UI/GetScreen.aspx?Screen=" 
    + encodeURIComponent(targetScreen) + "&Date=" + encodeURIComponent(Date()));        
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution so +1 but will grant to a different poster as using an `Image` object gives me the additional control I want

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function UpdateScreen() {

   var imgSrc = "./AJAX/UI/GetScreen.aspx?Screen=" + encodeURIComponent(targetScreen) + "&Date=" + encodeURIComponent(Date()),
       img = new Image();

   img.onload = function() {
    $("#Screenshot").attr("src", img.src );           
       setTimeout(UpdateScreen, 3000);
   };

   img.src = imgSrc;

}
```

Comment: Ideal solution thank - The only reason I granted to Josh is that he anwered slightly faster